# Include nested fields as result items in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a datatype which has a list of the same datatype as nested fields. I want to query the types and get results from the outer and inner items. Here is a small example what I want to achieve:

```
    PUT /testindex?pretty=true
    {
      "mappings": {
        "entry": {
          "dynamic": false,
          "properties": {
            "description": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "entries": {
              "type": "nested",
              "dynamic": false,
              "properties": {
                "description": {
                  "type": "text"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    PUT /testindex/entry/1?pretty=true
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "",
      "entries": [
        {
          "id": 1, "description": "lorem ipsum 11"
        },
        {
          "id": 1, "description": "lorem ipsum 22"
        },
        {
          "id": 1, "description": "dolor sit amet"
        }
      ]
    }

  PUT /testindex/entry/2?pretty=true&refresh=true
  {
    "id": 2, "description": "lorem ipsum", "entries": []
  }
```

The parent either has a description or a list. The inner type always has just a description and the Id of the parent. When I search now I want to get **a total count of 4**. Also, when I search for Description starting with 'lorem' **the result should contains 3 items**. Is something possible?

Comment: I dont understand the need for nesting, sicne parent id is repeated, cant you store it as `{"id":1,"descriptions":["lorem1","lorem2","lorem3"]}`?

Comment: No, this is a very small example. In real the type is much bigger. I need to store calendar entries. Also I have repeatable entries which I need to store and query in the index as well (in the DB such entries are stored completely different). For better handling such repeatable entries I am trying to keep these groups together, like mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [nested `inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) feature like below.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "description": "lorem"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "entries",
            "query": {
              "match_phrase": {
                "entries.description": "lorem"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: After reading the doc I think nested fields are not the right way. It can be that the number of the nested items can be very high and this should be avoided. I think I have to flatten the list and store it in single fields. Unfortunately... because I would have less effort with updates and deletes with something like a container element of related items. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yep, properly modeling your data is a very important aspect of the solution.